# Accessing Structure in objective C class makes error on XCode 4.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, ios5

In my iPhone app, I am using structure and access it from Objective C UIViewController class, In one of my AudioInput.h file, I have the below:

```
   typedef struct
    {
        AudioStreamBasicDescription format;
        AudioQueueRef queue;
        AudioQueueBufferRef buffers[ NUM_AUDIO_BUFFERS ];
        SampleBuffer samples;
        bool running;
        bool done;

        UInt32 playPos;

    }   AudioRecording;
```

In My ViewController MainViewController.m I implemented the `AudioInputCallback()` as below:

```
static void AudioInputCallback(
    void *userData,
    AudioQueueRef queue,
    AudioQueueBufferRef buffer,
    const AudioTimeStamp *startTime,
    UInt32 numPackets,
    const AudioStreamPacketDescription *packetDescriptions
)
{
    // TRACE( "AudioInputCallback\n" );

    MainViewController *controller = (MainViewController *) userData;
    AudioRecording *audioRecording = & controller->audioRecording;

    if( audioRecording->done )
    {
        TRACE( "AudioInputCallback: done\n" );
        return;
    }
    if( numPackets == 0 && audioRecording->format.mBytesPerPacket > 0 )
    {
        numPackets = buffer->mAudioDataByteSize / audioRecording->format.mBytesPerPacket;
    }
    if( numPackets == 0 )
    {
        TRACE( "not packets received\n" );
        return;
    }

    const SInt16 *inSamples = (const SInt16 *) buffer->mAudioData;
    const UInt32 remain = audioRecording->samples.size - audioRecording->samples.count;
    if( numPackets > remain )
    {
        numPackets = remain;
    }
    if( numPackets == 0 )
    {
        TRACE( "AudioInputCallback: no packets received\n" );
    }
    if( numPackets > 0 )
    {
        /*  Save samples.  */
        if( audioRecording->samples.data )
        {
            UInt16 *in = (UInt16 *) inSamples;
            UInt16 *out = (UInt16 *)( audioRecording->samples.data + audioRecording->samples.count );
            for( UInt32 i = 0; i < numPackets; ++i )
            {
                *out ++ = ntohs( *in++ );
            }
        }
        audioRecording->samples.count += numPackets;
    }

    if( audioRecording->samples.count < audioRecording->samples.size )
    {
        OSStatus result = AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer( queue, buffer, 0, NULL );
        if( result )
        {
            TRACE( "AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(..) failed with status %d\n", result );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        TRACE( "AudioInputCallback: enough material, stop recording\n" );
        audioRecording->done = true;
        AudioQueueStop( audioRecording->queue, true );
    }

    [controller performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(bufferFilled) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

In this method on the below line It gives error as "instance variable is protected"

```
MainViewController *controller = (MainViewController *) userData;
AudioRecording *audioRecording = & controller->audioRecording;
```

This error is occurs while running for iOS 5 with XCode 4.2 but the same code is running without any error building for below iOS 5 in XCode 4.0.2.

Can anyone help me why this error occurs? and your ideas to solve this is welcome!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's nothing to do with your structure, it's to do with how you've defined the members of your UIViewController subclass. Take a look at this :

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController
{
@public
    AudioRecording audioRecording1;

@protected // This is the default
    AudioRecording audioRecording2;

@private
    AudioRecording audioRecording3;
}
@end
```

Here, this controller has three `AudioRecording` members. However, only `audiorecording1` can be access directly from outside the class. `audiorecording3` cannot be accessed by anything other than the `MainViewController` and `audiorecording2` can be accessed by `MainViewController` and any subclasses of it.

You need to make your audiorecording public if you want to access it directly without going though an accessor method (or a property).

Comment: Thanks DeanWomboume, I tried this, It works in earlier version of Xcode from Xcode 4.0.1, But In Xcode 4.2 for iOS 5 is not working gives the following ERROR:

ld: library not found for -lfaxpp
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Comment: That's a missing library - nothing to do with this problem :) I don't know why it's not working in XCode 4.2 though - check your project library search path etc? And ask it as a new question on stackoverflow ;)